# Editing a number of lists of a SharePoint site together

Tags: list

I don't know if this is the right place to ask but I am creating a powerapp canvas based app. My data source are saved as SharePoint list files. I have to change the column type from single line of text to Choice for all those list files. As I have a very large number of lists ( Around 100) and each list contains 30-40 columns , changing one by one seems impossible. Is there a way I can change the column type of all the lists at once? Even a way to change the column type of all columns of a single list at once would ease the work a bit!! Please help.  If it's not  possible directly, is it possible in javascript? can you nudge me to the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Content Type and add that one to all the list.

See: [How to make the Content Types available on all SharePoint Sites via the Content Type Gallery](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-make-the-content-types-available-on-all-sharepoint-sites-via-the-content-type-gallery/)